# integral of the laplacian to some power

Tags: complex-geometry, differential-equations, elliptic-pde

I want to know the space of functions where the following quantity is uniformly bounded from above 
$$\int_{K} (\Delta u)^j d\lambda< C,$$
where K is a compact and j is an integer number greater than 1.

Comment: You mean some Sobolev space or something different? It is a bit confusing what you write.

Comment: I know this inequality is true for u in $ u\in W^{2,p} for some p, but I want my constant C to be independently of u. Then i am looking in which space of functions this is true.